# How can I open URL externally without using packages in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, url, redirect

I have this test project where we are asked to create an app that opens URL with external browser without using third party packages.

Comment: you need to use `MethodChannel` and implement your code for each platform, on android use `Intent`

Answer (score 0):

[Package http in the pub](https://pub.dev/packages/http) is a first-party package (not third-party) maintained by Google.  This package unifies the differences between using XHR on the web and direct http calls elsewhere.

Comment: Please how can I use this package to URL on external web browser